# Do young singers need to rotate their roles but not older ones?

Tags: voice, musical-theatre

This question is based on the following line in the [Wikipedia article on Éponine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89ponine) (a character from *Les Miserables*):

> Éponine is also featured in the stage musical adaptation. She is played by two actors, a young girl for Young Éponine in the Montfermeil scenes, and by a young woman for the adolescent Éponine in the later Parisian scenes. *Actresses playing Young Éponine and Young Cosette sometimes interchange roles in different performances to equalize performance opportunities and vocal strain.*

(emphasis mine)

Is this something only young actresses do, and not older ones? If so, why - is there a biological explanation, or something else? The sentence is not cited, so it could also be wrong, in which case that would also be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds unlikely. The young Cosette is a relatively demanding singing role for a child. The young Eponine is a silent role, so presumably far easier to cast. Since there are usually strict limits on how often children are allowed to perform, it would be illogical to 'waste' a valuable Cosette and have her play Eponine. But maybe they do it anyway to give their Cosettes a break from singing.

For a different show with two similar child roles (e.g. 'The Sound of Music'), companies will often train children for both parts so they are more flexible in their planning.

Comment: Might be nice to address the broader topics of voice care. I'm not sure that "cast management practices" is on-topic here, but "taking care of your voice" is.

Comment: @AndyBonner Voice care is already covered in numerous other questions here. I don't think the question is quite off-topic, but I agree it's borderline.

Comment: Any idea why there are usually strict limits on how often children are allowed to perform? I'm again wondering about a biological explanation, if there is one.

Comment: @Allure This is about professional theater. Normally it's forbidden to employ children, but there are certain exceptions like for theatres. There's always an upper limit on how many days a year a child is allowed to work.